# XCTests are flaky when run through command line or through jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

There are bunch of 120 cases, which runs perfectly well when run through xcode

But when run through Jenkins i get below errors

1)  Failed to terminate com.test.app1:500 after 60.0s; state is still `Running Active` (3), should be `Not Running` (1)

2) testApp3, Launch token from Xcode

3)  testApp2, launch status response from Xcode

Why do they come ? what could be the reason ?
whats the solution for stabilising this

Tried

1) Restarting the device before test run (manually)
2) Resetting the device before test run (manually)
3) Uninstalled the application before every run

Still the issue exists, one or the other test case gets failed.